# How can I dispatch from Registration Servlet to Login Servlet POST method

Tags: java, redirect, post, servlets, model-view-controller

how to redirect the request from registration servlet to login servlet POST method . i wanna do this because the user after registration, i redirect him to the homepage as already logged.

here is my Registration servlet

```
     -------
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String nome=request.getParameter("Nome");
    String cognome=request.getParameter("Cognome");
    String email=request.getParameter("Email");
    String password=request.getParameter("Password");
    String documento=request.getParameter("Documento");
    String num_documento=request.getParameter("NumeroDocumento");

    Utente u = new Utente(email,password,nome,cognome,documento,num_documento);
    System.out.println("qui");

    RequestDispatcher d;
    UtenteDAO ud = new UtenteDAO();
    if(ud.doSave(u)){
        d = request.getRequestDispatcher();
        d.forward(request, response);
        }else{
            request.setAttribute("err", true);
            d=request.getRequestDispatcher("Registrazione.jsp");
            d.forward(request, response);
        }

}
```

sorry for my English :(

Answer (score 0):

You can set the response of your servlet to status code 301. Something like below.

```
response.sendRedirect("https://www.google.com");
```

This will instruct the browser to go to www.google.com, you can replace this with your URL.